# Android activity written to internal storage

Tags: android, android-activity

I am writing an Android app where I write state to save files. I erroneous ran under the premise that the only files in a applications internal storage, are the ones that it wrote there....so I did not parse by extension.

Turns out there was a file there and it was named after my main activity...

Called "namspace.applicationname.MainAcitivty".

What is this file for? Is it a serialized version of my activity?

Comment: It is an internal storage for your app, simply not allowed access for any other users except the rooted devices. If you have uninstalled/remove cache of it, the folder will also be removed, but update of version of app will not affect the files inside.

Comment: So there is a folder in my internal storage by default?

Comment: yup, for each application, within Android folder, path data/data/<packageName>

Comment: But just to clarify there is a folder WITHIN my internal storage, and that file was not a serialized Activity? I understand what internal storage is, but there was an existing file within my external storage.

Comment: The folder is not using for serialising activity, but to store pref / db / any things you want to put inside

Comment: I think you are confused about the question....I understand that internal storage folder for an app is for anything I want to put inside. But already inside my internal app directory existed a file that was already there...